# beautifulsoup/selenium find element below another

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Quick question I never had to do this before basically I have following HTML:

```
<tr class="a"> content </tr>
<tr class="item">content</tr>
```

And I need to tell soup to take first element below already found tr with class a

I tried `element_with_class_a.find_previous(class_='item').text` but that finds previous one

And I cannot find all and match it by index because number sometimes might not be equal to class a

**Edit:
I shared answer below it can be done with find_next()**

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering quick solution is:

element_with_class_a.find_next('tr', class_='item')